# C++ Delete [] Operator

Tags: c++, heap-memory, delete-operator

Does

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float* temps = new float[10];

    float* temps2 = temps;

    delete[] temps2;

    return 0;
}
```

have the same working as

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float* temps = new float[10];

    float* temps2 = temps;

    delete[] temps;

    return 0;
}
```

?

Do they both release all the allocated memory? Or do I have to delete[] the original pointer?

Comment: Not the best dupe - I've reopened - the rules differ slightly for `delete` and `delete[]` and the duplicate was for the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are fine.

So long as the pointer has exactly the same type (a change to or from `const` is allowed), you can call `delete[]`.

(Note that for `new` and `delete` the pointer can be polymorphically related, but that's **not** true for `new[]` and `delete[]`).

Comment: Thanks. Btw, how does delete[] know the size of the dynamic array?

Comment: @DarkoNaito_09: A C++ runtime will maintain a table of allocated sizes somewhere.

Comment: so why doesn't c++ provide a feature to get the size of an array?

Comment: @DarkoNaito_09: Over-allocation is one reason. If you ask for say 7 elements there's a reasonable chance the runtime might allocate 8. Then it would have to remember that you only wanted 7.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I very much doubt that such a table exists. I always assumed that the size was stored in the area preceding the array. (g++ stores the size in the preceding word, at least for arrays of built-in type.)

Comment: @TonyK: You're right. I wish I could edit my previous comment. Silly SO comment edit rules... I could run for moderator, I guess and if successful, make the comment edit, then resign.

Comment: The main reason is that not all pointers will point at an array, dynamically allocated or otherwise.   All means of retrieving the size of an array given a pointer will make assumptions about what that pointer points at - and, if the assumption made is invalid, the behaviour will be undefined.    There are so many things a pointer can point at - not all of which are associated with a retrievable size - that trying to specify such things would be difficult, let alone trying to write code to retrieve the size correctly.

Comment: @TonyK • on my platform, `new[]` stores the size (in terms of object count) as a pair (pointer, count) in the allocated memory table of the `new[]` heap.  It isn't stored in the area preceding the array.  But that's an implementation detail, and can vary by compiler & platform.  (My platform, with a diagnostic build, also puts in preceding and trailing memory set to a particular byte value, to detect write underruns and overruns.)